# Jumbotron at footer not sticking to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a fixed footer from a `jumbotron` including a `text area` and a `button`. This is what I have now at the end of `<body>`:

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid position-fixed fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
    
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Message: </span>
      </div>
      
      <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
      
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Send</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this `jumbotron` doesn't stick to the bottom of the page. It stays about `50px` above the bottom, it's so ugly and I don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the default `.jumbotron` has `margin-bottom: 2rem;`. Removing that bottom margin will fix the issue.

You can also do your custom style:

```css
.jumbotron.fixed-bottom {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

By the way, you don't need `.position-fixed` class. `.fixed-bottom` will do the fixed position for you!